# set a listener for widgets in items of a listview

Tags: android

I meet a problem developing an android project.
Using adapter, I place many items in a ListView, and there is an ImageButton in each item. Now I want to set a click listener for these ImageButtons. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This achieves your desired result. Its functionality is the button itself has a click response different from the container, which also has a response.

MainActivity.java

```
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list);
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list );
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(
                    new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                android.view.View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,
                                    "List item clicked",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                });
            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            items.add( "item1");
            items.add( "item2");
            items.add( "item3");
            ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter( this, items);
            lv.setAdapter( adapter );
        }
    }
```

ListAdapter.java

```
 import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.List;

    public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public ListAdapter(Context context,
                            List<String> items ) { 
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }

        public int getCount() {                        
            return items.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {     
            return items.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {  
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
            String item = items.get(position);
            View v = null;
            if( convertView != null )
                v = convertView;
            else
                v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.item, parent, false);
            TextView itemTV = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.item);
            itemTV.setText( item );
            ImageButton button = 
                (ImageButton)v.findViewById( R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(
                        new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText( context,
                                        "ImageButton clicked",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            return v;
        }

        private Context context;
        private List<String> items;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
    }
```

item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/emo_im_cool" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:id="@+id/list" />
```

Try it out and hopefully you can see what's going on to learn what you need

Comment: Yes. But how can I set a listener for a button in an item instead of the whole item?